# Making a div height dynamic so there is not a gap with extra content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I'm trying to get this div to always stretch it's height to touch the bottom when the left column has extra content added to it. In the image you see this. What CSS or JS tricks will work on this?

HTML:

```
<div class="content-sections" style="">
  <div class="grid-container columns">
    <div class="left-section grid-55 mobile-100">
     <div class="title">
       <!-- DYNAMIC TEXT -->
     </div>
     <div class="content">
       <!-- DYNAMIC TEXT -->
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="top-section grid-45 mobile-100">
     <div class="top-title">
       <!-- DYNAMIC TEXT -->
     </div>
     <div class="content-item">
       <!-- DYNAMIC TEXT -->
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="bottom-section grid-45 mobile-100"> // THIS SECTION NEEDS HEIGHT TO ALWAYS STRETCH TO FOOTER
     <div class="cta">
       <!-- DYNAMIC TEXT -->
     </div>
     <div class="button">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.content-sections {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.content-sections div.columns {
    max-width: 4000px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 7.65%;
}

div.content-sections div.columns .left-section {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 67px;
    padding-bottom: 156px;
    padding-right: 8.375%;
}

div.content-sections div.columns .left-section .title {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: $mediumFont;
    color: rgb(35, 47, 50);
    line-height: 1.042;
}

div.content-sections div.columns .left-section .bodytext {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: $regularFont;
    color: rgb(35, 47, 50);
    line-height: 1.5625;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

div.content-sections div.columns .top-section {
    color: white;
    background-color: #fb8c20;
    padding-top: 67px;
    padding-bottom: 156px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 16.125%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.content-sections div.columns .top-section .top-title {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: $lightFont;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    line-height: 1.042;
}

div.content-sections div.columns .top-section .content-item {
    background-image: url(/images/check-mark.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 5px;
    padding-left: 1.875em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: $mediumFont;
    line-height: 1.5625;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

div.content-sections div.columns .bottom-section {
    color: white;
    background-color: #232f32;
    padding-top: 56px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.content-sections div.columns .bottom-section .cta {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-family: $lightFont;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `height: 100%;` on the section that needs to stretch?

Comment: Gave us the HTML but no CSS? Nice one, we can do a lot with that.

Comment: @Tom I have, but no luck. Then I was looking to see if there is calc() trick

Comment: Can we see the CSS, please?

Comment: @Ruddy I love comments like yours. No help. I'll provide the CSS but I'm mainly asking if anyone has had this issue and found a trick/hack to this.

Comment: Yes, setting `height: 100%` to father element - and if necessary the 'granpa' one - should work.  A [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/89jpk7co/1/) of how works.

Comment: @tjoenz You should think about it before hand, without CSS its hard to see what you have done with other elements. There could be a hundred reasons causing this problem. Taking wild guesses is not helping and you should be helping us (with all the information we need) to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following style for the last div

```
<div class="bottom-section grid-45 mobile-100" style="display:table;height:100%;"> // THIS SECTION NEEDS HEIGHT TO ALWAYS STRETCH TO FOOTER
 <div class="cta">
   <!-- DYNAMIC TEXT -->
 </div>
 <div class="button">
 </div>
```